# How to change Spark submit (via yarn) report frequency

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

By default once the Yarn job starts spark will print every second:

```
INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1603121715572_605013 (state: RUNNING)
```

Is it possible to change this to happen once every 30 seconds?