# Reduce frequency of Spark Streaming Info logs

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

When I deploy my spark streaming job and run it via spark2-submit I get every second such a log message:

```
21/02/24 21:45:27 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1612163470992_382017 (state: RUNNING)
```

Is it somehow possible to reduce the interval of such an output (e.g. to every 10 min)? Does anybody know how to do it?
I am using Scala Spark 2.3.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231250/how-to-change-spark-submit-via-yarn-report-frequency)

Found it! It's handled by the `spark.yarn.report.interval` config. (at least on spark v2.4.5). I was able to change it by adding the following to `spark-submit`:

```bash
 --conf spark.yarn.report.interval=30000
```

Note: the value is in milliseconds